# XSD Validation Error - Complex Type referenced in same Definition

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to write my first XSD . . . The XSD is as follows and does not validate.

```
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   
    <xsd:complexType name="Hdr">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="ID" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>    
    <xsd:element name="Header" type="xsd:Hdr" />
</xsd:schema>
```

I am using http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/ for the validation

I get this error

> Not valid.Error - Line 7, 49: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xsd:Hdr'. 
>       It was detected that 'xsd:Hdr' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'null'. 
>       If this is the incorrect namespace, perhaps the prefix of 'xsd:Hdr' needs to be changed. 
>       If this is the correct namespace, then an appropriate 'import' tag should be added to 'null'.
>       Error - Line 7, 49: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 49; src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xsd:Hdr' to a(n) 'type definition' component.

I cannot figure out what is wrong in my XSD. Could someone please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  <xsd:element name="Header" type="xsd:Hdr" />
```

to

```
  <xsd:element name="Header" type="Hdr" />
```

If a target namespace were defined, you would use its prefix to reference `Hdr`, but you'd never use the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace to make such a reference.